# In App Purchase issue in IPhone

Tags: in-app-purchase

I have integrated in app purchase for consumable products in my app. When user make purchase, some data gets uploaded to our server. So I have code to post notification for successful & failed transaction. Depending on notification, it calls the respective methods for uploading data or informing user about failed transaction. My problem is that the method finishTransaction gets called multiple times and thus posts notifications multiple times. Due to this data gets uploaded multiple times. Please suggest any solution. Here is part of my code:

```
- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful
{
   //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"user_id"];

    // remove the transaction from the payment queue.
    //[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    [myque finishTransaction:transaction];

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:transaction, @"transaction" , nil];
    if (wasSuccessful)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```